# SQL antijoin with multiple keys

Tags: sql, subquery, left-join, anti-join

I'd like to implement an antijoin on two table but using two keys so that the result is all rows in Table A that do not contain the combinations of [key_1, key_2] found in Table B.  How can I write this query in SQL?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those are not **multiple** "keys" but a **single** "composite key".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an anti-`left join`, the logic is:

```
select a.*
from tablea a 
left join tableb b on b.key_1 = a.key_1 and b.key_2 = a.key_2
where b.key_1 is null
```

As for me, I like to implement such logic with `not exists`, because I find that it is more expressive about the intent:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
where not exists (
    select 1 from tableb b where b.key_1 = a.key_1 and b.key_2 = a.key_2
)
```

The `not exists` query would take advantage of an index on `tableb(key_1, key_2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*
from table_a a 
left anti join table_b b on a.key_1 = b.key_1 and a.key_2 = b.key_2;
```